# How can I split string into variables?

Tags: python, string, list

I need to split the string into variables something like:

```
string = "Hello: My name is..." 
title, separator, my_name_is = string.partition(": ")
```

But, I need a string with "My name is..." always in variable 'my_name_is' even if in the initial string will be only "My name is...".
I think it could be done something like this:

```
>>>string = "My name is..." 
>>>title, separator, my_name_is = string.partition(": ")
>>>if my_name_is == "":
>>>   my_name_is = title
>>>print(my_name_is)
My name is...
```

but I must have this code in one line and can't use the RE (task for the school)

Comment: "It must be code in one line"? Why? I can't think of one good reason where that's ever an absolute constraint. Also, where is the "if statement"?

Comment: this is s task from school and in assignment is "one line"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: @VojtaJahoda: Does the assignment force, to return `title` and `separator` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be in one line without any imports, then this will do the job quite nicely:

```
string = "Hello: My name is..." 
(title, my_name_is), separator = string.split(': ') if ':' in string else (None, string), ':'

print(title)
print(separator)
print(my_name_is)

# Hello
# :
# My name is...
```

This works also if the `string` has no 'title':

```
string = "My name is..." 
(title, my_name_is), separator = string.split(': ') if ':' in string else (None, string), ':'

print(title)
print(separator)
print(my_name_is)

# None
# :
# My name is...
```

I would never ever do such awful oneliners though.